# MinSDK UI/Theme always gets loaded, TargetSDK Theme is not

Tags: android, sdk, target, min

I have an android project that I migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio. My MinSDK is set to 8. TargetSDK=19.

However in all instances SDK=8 UI/Theme gets displayed, even if running on 4.4 devices.

I believe this is due to missing themes/style files.

Has anyone faced a similar problem, and how to go about correcting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start off would be the *styles.xml* files under **res -> values-v11** & **res -> values-v14**. In the off chance they're missing, you'll have to add them there.

Here, is a sample of what a *styles.xml* looks like by default for **values-v14** :

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

Of course if you need the ActionBar you can remove the *NoActionBar* above. The file would look the same for **values-v11** too. Also, in case you're using the support ActionBar then the style would be defined thus :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

Comment: This was the issue, thanks! In my case I had to actually manually add the values-v14 folder and create the styles.xml based on your sample. However this didnt work right away as I had a custom theme. Once I removed custom theme, proper UI Theme started loading.

Comment: That's good. Just outta curiosity though...did you export the ADT/Eclipse project as Gradle build files and then import the same into Android Studio or did you do something else?

Comment: I believe I just transferred the source.

Comment: I can't say for certain but that *may* have been a cause, the next time you ought to try the Gradle method, it could lead to less hassles IMHO :) Anyways. good luck with your development!